# awk and egrep for regular expression

Tags: linux, awk, command-line, regular-expression, pcregrep

I am very new to unix!

trying to figure out, from a fastq file how many reads have 3 or MORE As in a row?

I used egrep 'A{3}' to tell me how many AAA I have. But now I want to know >= 3 AAA in a row. But >= doesn't work. Can I use awk to help me determine this?

Also, how can I use regular expression to determine How many reads have a run of 4 or more As followed by something other than a T? (G C or A) 
So A has to be >= 4, and followed by GCorA

EDIT: When I mean to say 3As in a row, I mean something like this: GGCTAAAAAACGGAT

Comment: Welcome! Could you post a sample text and the desired output?

Comment: When I read `I want to know >= 3 AAA in a row` I thought you were trying to get a count of lines where `AAA` appears 3 or more times on a line, e.g. `fooAAAbarAAAetcAAAetc.` but all the answers so far are interpreting your question differently from me and, in some cases, from each other. Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and provide concise, testable sample input and expected output that adequately demonstrates those requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you three or more `a`s you could use: `a{3,}`.  For example:

```
$ echo a | grep -E 'a{3,}'
$ echo aa | grep -E 'a{3,}'
$ echo aaa | grep -E 'a{3,}'
aaa
$ echo aaaa | grep -E 'a{3,}'
aaaa
$ echo aaaaaaaaaa | grep -E 'a{3,}'
aaaaaaaaaa
```

If you want 3 or more `a`s followed by something that's not a `t`, you could use `a{3,}[^t]`.  For example:

```
$ echo aaa | grep -E 'a{3,}[^t]'
$ echo aaat | grep -E 'a{3,}[^t]'
$ echo aaax | grep -E 'a{3,}[^t]'
aaax
```

Note, however, that an `a` isn't a `t`, so that'll match something like 'aaaa'; the first three `a`s followed by a character that isn't a `t` (in this case, `a`).

```
$ echo aaaa | grep -E 'a{3,}[^t]'
aaaa
```

If you want the string to end in something that is neither `a` nor `t`, you could use: `a{3,}[^at]`.  For example:

```
$ echo aaaa | grep -E 'a{3,}[^ta]'
$ echo aaaaaaaa | grep -E 'a{3,}[^ta]'
$ echo aaaaaaaattt | grep -E 'a{3,}[^ta]'
$ echo aaaaaaaab | grep -E 'a{3,}[^ta]'
aaaaaaaab
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the count of sequences of three or more `A`s, try

```
awk '{print gsub (/AAAA*/, "&")}' file
3
4
4
1
```

For your second request, adapt above like

```
awk '{print gsub (/AAAAA*[CG]/, "&")}' file
```

"followed by A" is already covered by the A* pattern.

Comment: You can use `/AAA+/` or `/A{3,}/` instead of `/AAAA*/`.

Answer (score 0):

> from a fastq file how many reads have 3 or MORE As in a row

Since it's a fastq format file, you only want to look at the actual sequence lines, not all lines, to get an accurate count. You can do this by using the `NR` variable to restrict matches to just the second line of each 4-line sequence block:

```
awk 'NR%4 == 2 && /AAA/ { count++ } END { print count+0 }' foo.fastq
```

> How many reads have a run of 4 or more As followed by something other than a T? (G C or A)

```
awk 'NR%4 == 2 && /AAAA([^T]|$)/ { count++ } END { print count+0 }' foo.fastq
```

(Note that this will match `AAAAAT` because it has 4 A's followed by another A)